# POST http://localhost:8000/api/project/create/ 400 (Bad Request) error when sending POST data from the React app using fetch() to Django API

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a simple DRF + ReactJS app, but when I came across making a POST data from React app to the Django API, this error happens on the web console `POST http://localhost:8000/api/project/create/ 400 (Bad Request)` and it says the problem is on my `Create.jsx`

This is my `Create.jsx` file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
const Create = () => {

const history = useNavigate()
const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
const [body, setBody] = useState("")

const createProject = async () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/project/create/', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        title: JSON.stringify(title),
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
    console.log('title', title)
    console.log('BODY', body)
}



return (
    <div className="create-project">
        
        <p>
            <input type="text" onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} value={title} ></input> 
            <textarea type="text" onChange={e => setBody(e.target.value)} value={body}></textarea>
            <button onClick={createProject}>Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>
)
}

export default Create
```

And this is the APIView in django:
**views.py**

```
class CreateProject(CreateAPIView):
   queryset = Project.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

**urls.py** if needed:

```
path('project/create/', CreateProject.as_view(), name="create-project"),
```

Comment: is there a reason you're JSON stringifying your title and body? I had a similar situation but all I had to do was `title: title`

Comment: @Eddy No there isn't any reason for me to use JSON.stringify, but I used because I thought if I didn't It will give me the same problem, I tried removing and just doing it like `title: title,` and still has the same issue and error